# what is the correct way to update ref values with returned object of refs in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm using the nuxt3 useAsyncData composable which returns an object of refs: {data, pending, error}.

I need to have some existing refs available when the component mounts as this data is fetched after some user action and needs to be available in the template on mount.

Is there a better way to update the exiting refs (hasError, isLoading, searchItems) with the returned refs from the getSearchResults function?

In the second example I update the refs while destructuring but I seem to lose reactivity this way.

**How i'm doing it now:**

```js
const hasError = ref(false);
const isLoading = ref(false);
const searchQuery = ref('');
const searchItems = ref([]);

watch(searchQuery, async () => {
  // Fetch data
  const { data, pending, error } = await getSearchResults(searchQuery.value);
  
  // Update Refs
  isLoading.value = pending.value;
  hasError.value = error.value;
  searchItems.value = data.value;
});

const getSearchResults = async (query) => {
  if (!query) return;
  return await useAsyncData('searchItems', () =>
    $fetch('/api/search', {
      params: {
        query: query,
      },
    })
  );
};
```

**Setting values while destructuring - Doesn't work:**

```js
const hasError = ref(false);
const isLoading = ref(false);
const searchQuery = ref('');
const searchItems = ref([]);

watch(searchQuery, async () => {
  ({ data: searchItems.value, pending: isLoading.value, error: hasError.value } = await getSearchResults(searchQuery.value));

});

const getSearchResults = async (query) => {
  if (!query) return;
  return await useAsyncData('searchItems', () =>
    $fetch('/api/search', {
      params: {
        query: query,
      },
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch

Comment: I have but its the same problem. Im just unsure if this is the correct pattern and if it can be simplified like the second example by updating existing refs while destructuring the return data.

`1) Setup some refs for initial null values in template.
2) Fetch data and return some refs.
3) Update the initial refs with the new data.`

Comment: Thanks for adding more info to your question. I think what you need is an API to fetch data and another  API for updating the data. Are you using an external API or is it stored inside the `server` folder?